# Show the inequality $ |f(x)-p(x)| \leq h^{n+1}* \frac{||f^{n+1}||_{\infty}}{4(n+1)}$

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, numerical-calculus, lagrange-interpolation

Let $ f \in C^{n+1}([a,b])$ and a polynom p $\in P_{n} $.
The support points $ x_{i} = a +ih , i =0,...,n$ are equidistant with $ h \in \mathbb{R} $ so that $ x_{n}=b$.

Show

$ |f(x)-p(x)| \leq h^{n+1}* \frac{||f^{n+1}||_{\infty}}{4(n+1)} \forall  x \in [a,b]$.

My first idea is to show this with induction but I don´t get the start. But in lesson we have a corollar that for the interpolation error applies

$ |f(x)-p(x)| \leq |\omega (x)|* max_{\xi \in I}\frac{|f^{n+1}(\xi)|}{(n+1)!} ,x \in I=[a,b]$.
With $\omega (x) = \prod_{j=0}^n (x-x_{j})$.

Maybe this could be usefull?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the error formula for polynomial interpolation
$$
|f(x)-p(x)|\le\frac{|f^{(n+1)}(\xi)|}{(n+1)!}\prod_{k=0}^n|x-x_k|
$$
for some $\xi$ inside the interval spanned by the $x_k$ and $x$.

See [There is a way to determine error of an interpolation outside of the given range](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3278945/115115), [Error term in polynomial interpolation of non-differentiable function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3386255/115115), or similar [interpolation error using higher derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783551/115115)

Comment: I think I got it  but it wasn´t easy to find out how to use this formular to get the right term.